# Whole page re-rendering instead of only the component containing the updated property

Tags: reactjs

In the following React App code I am setting a useState property which is bound to a function component called Header. What is not shown in the demo code is that I am calling the triggerTestProp function from another child component which is located in e.g. the HomePage component.

However whenever I set this property, not only does the banner re-render but also the whole page which contains the header. I am using React Router for navigation as seen in the demo code. Any idea why the whole page gets rerendered but not only the header as expected?

```
function App() {
  const [testProp, setTestProp] = useState(
    "defaultVal"
  );

  function triggerTestProp(newTestProp: string) {
   setTestProp(newTestProp);
  }

  return (    
    <div>
      <Header banner={testProp}></Backdrop>
      <Router>
        <Switch>         
          <Route path="/home/">
            <HomePage></HomePage>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/:id">
            <DetailPage></DetailPage>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <HomePage></HomePage>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you set state in App.js `setTestProp(newTestProp);`, it rerenders, which in turn causes all its child Components to rerender.

To prevent child components from rerendering when their props or state does not change, use `React.memo()`. export child compoents as `export default React.memo(HOmePage)`

Comment: I have a similar problem, but somehow this method doesnt work for me